# User defined function in VBA not "array-firendly"

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, udf

I have the following user-defined functions created:

```
Public Function LNt(LMiu As Double, LSigma As Double, t As Double)
Application.Volatile
LNt = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormDist(Log(t) / Log(2.71828182845905), LMiu, LSigma, False) / t
End Function
```

and

```
Public Function IntLNt(LMiu As Double, LSigma As Double, Lower As Double, Upper As Double, Step As Integer)
Application.Volatile

Dim Delta As Double
Dim I As Double

Delta = ((Log(Upper) / Log(2.71828182845905)) - (Log(Lower) / Log(2.71828182845905))) / Step

I = ((Log(Upper) / Log(2.71828182845905)) - (Log(Lower) / Log(2.71828182845905))) * (LNt(LMiu, LSigma, Lower) + LNt(LMiu, LSigma, Upper)) / (2 * Step)

For n = 2 To Step
I = I + LNt(LMiu, LSigma, Lower + Delta * (n - 1)) * Delta
Next

IntLNt = I
End Function
```

When I tried to run the formula in spreadsheet for various values of "Lower" and "Upper" (for summation through 1 to n), using

```
    =SUMPRODUCT(IntLNt(LMiu,LSigma,ROW(INDIRECT("1:8")),ROW(INDIRECT("1:8"))))
```

The result (when I evaluate the formula), does not return the values 1 through 8 within the array. It just returns the value 1.

Where is the mistake? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `IntLNt` returns a single number. `SUMPRODUCT` expects [an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18494156/11683).

Comment: *"Where is the mistake?"* It is not a mistake, just that user-defined functions are not "array-enabled" by nature. If you want your UDF to be valid for arrays, you can't assume that, you need to write it differently.

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve? Your sample cell formula lacks the parameter `Step` which is not optional. And even if it would work as an array formula the result would be an array of `0`s always since `Lower` and `Upper` are always equal.

Comment: All. Thanks for the helps so far.

Comment: All. Thanks for the helps so far. What I am trying to achieve, is I would like to sum a specific function (that is not available in Excel), from k=1 to k=n. I have managed to do this well with existing function in Excel using "SUMPRODUCT" and "ROW" functions. I can't do that with the function above, as it's not set-up to accept arrays. I have tried to use "()" after "t", "Upper", and "Lower", and size the "()" from 1 to n, and it's still not working. I have made an interim solution to use columns in excel to do the summation from 1 to n, but it's not efficient. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have an example of a UDF which can deal with arrays. This UDF takes two parameters. The first is x as a Double value. The other is a Variant. It can be either a single value or an array or a Range.

```
Public Function arrayFriendlyUDF(x As Double, vParam As Variant) As Variant
 'function which can get variant parameter vParam
 'either a single value or a range or an array literal
 'will return a single value or an array of results
 'it will only accept double values as single value, in range or in array literal

 Dim adParam As Variant, dParam As Double, aParam() As Double
 Dim aResult() As Double
 Dim i As Integer

 adParam = vParam
 'if vParam is a single value, then adParam also is a single value
 'if vParam is a range, then adParam is a variant array from this range's values
 'if vParam is a array literal, then adParam is a variant array from this array literal

 If TypeName(adParam) = "Variant()" Then 'we have a variant array
  'it could be one dimensional (row vector) or two dimensional (column vector)
  'we will only process one dimensional array, so we must transform if needed
  i = 0
  For Each vParam In adParam
   ReDim Preserve aParam(i)
   aParam(i) = vParam
   i = i + 1
  Next
 ElseIf TypeName(adParam) = "Double" Then 'we have a single double value
  ReDim aParam(0)
  aParam(0) = adParam
 End If
 'now we have an array (one dimensional) in any case

 For i = LBound(aParam) To UBound(aParam)
  ReDim Preserve aResult(i)

  aResult(i) = x * aParam(i) 'this is the function's operation. simply x * {vParam} in this case

 Next

 If UBound(aResult) = 0 Then
  'if only one result
  arrayFriendlyUDF = aResult(0)
 Else
  'return the array of results
  arrayFriendlyUDF = aResult
 End If

End Function
```

This UDF can be used as:

`=arrayFriendlyUDF(2,3)` result = 6

`=arrayFriendlyUDF(2,A3)` result = 6 if `A3` contains 3

`=SUM(arrayFriendlyUDF(2,{1;2;3;4}))` result = 20 = sum n=1 to 4 (2 * n)

`=SUM(arrayFriendlyUDF(2,A1:D1))` result = 20 if `A1:D1` contains {1,2,3,4}

`=SUM(arrayFriendlyUDF(2,A1:A4))` result = 20 if `A1:A4` contains {1;2;3;4}

`{=SUM(arrayFriendlyUDF(2,ROW(1:4)))}` result = 20

`{=SUM(arrayFriendlyUDF(2,COLUMN(A:D)))}` result = 20

The last both formulas must be array formulas confirmed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Still not clear with your UDF approach. As said in the comment your sample cell formula lacks the parameter `Step` which is not optional. And even if it would work as an array formula - what we could achieve now -  the result would be an array of 0s always since `Lower` and `Upper` are always equal using `ROW(INDIRECT("1:8"))` for both.

Comment: Dear Axel. Thanks a lot for the help. Will give it a try. The parameter  `Step` is a value that will be input in the Worksheet. I think `Step` has to be written to accept arrays as well. Thanks!