# EXCEL SUM doesn't work with UDF in ARRAY

Tags: excel, vba

In my wooksheet I have cells: A1 = 1 and A2 = 2

This formula works of course in a cell of a sheet:

```
    =SUM(A1:A2) [correctly giving *3*]
```

But I do have values like : A1 : 1½ and A2 = 2½
but this array (CSE) formula doesn't work:

```
    {=SUM(myUserDefinedFkt(A1:A2))} [giving *#VALUE*, should have been *4*]
```

where myUserDefinedFkt could be as simple as (only an example):

```
    public function myUserDefinedFkt(value) as double
        if instr(1, value, "½" , 1)>0 then value = replace(value, "½", ".5")
        myUserDefinedFkt = value
    end function
```

I think it is right to use array formulas, but HOW?

EDIT. I've changed my function and the two cellvalues to be more precise!

Comment: You are passing a `Range` to your UDF which accepts a variant.  Your UDF is then trying to multiply that `Variant/Range` by 2 and fails (because you can't perform arithmetic operations on a range).

Comment: How to overcome that?

Comment: I think you would need to process each cell in `value` individually, placing the results into a Variant array (which has the same shape as the source range) and then pass that Variant array back as the UDF's result.  But that gets difficult unless you can restrict user input and what will happen with the result - e.g. do you need to allow input of `myUserDefinedFkt((A1:A2,B7))`, do you need to allow the result of the UDF to be used without a `SUM`, etc.

Comment: If the **only** thing you were going to do with the result is `SUM` it, it would be a simple thing to do the sum in the UDF itself.

Comment: I could of course use this way, but thought there was a more 'elegant' way of doing it than just looping through the values.

Comment: Array formulas would work by each component function handling arrays, not by repetitively invoking each function.  So you either need to change the UDF to accept/return an array, or get rid of the need to use an array formula by doing everything in the UDF.  Either way, you will need to change the UDF.

Comment: FWIW - Your current MCVE could be done using `{=SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A2,"½",".5")))}`, but I guess there is more to the code than the MCVE.

Comment: You're right, but I appreciate your stimulations of clarity :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a `UDF` can return an array and so can be used as array formula depends on the `UDF`. Even `Excels` native functions are **not** **all** usable in array context.

So at first we must have a `UDF` which can return an  array. In [User defined function in VBA not "array-firendly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792215/user-defined-function-in-vba-not-array-firendly/41844849) I have provided an approach for a prototype of an `arrayFriendlyUDF`.

Using this we can also solving the problem of this question:

UDF:

```
Public Function arrayFriendlyUDF(vParam As Variant) As Variant
 'function which can get variant parameter vParam
 'either a single value or a range or an array literal
 'will return a single value or an array of results
 'it will only accept double values or strings as single value, in range or in array literal

 Dim adParam As Variant, dParam As Double, aParam() As Variant
 Dim aResult() As Double
 Dim i As Integer

 adParam = vParam
 'if vParam is a single value, then adParam also is a single value
 'if vParam is a range, then adParam is a variant array from this range's values
 'if vParam is a array literal, then adParam is a variant array from this array literal

 If TypeName(adParam) = "Variant()" Then 'we have a variant array
  'it could be one dimensional (row vector) or two dimensional (column vector)
  'we will only process one dimensional array, so we must transform if needed
  i = 0
  For Each vParam In adParam
   ReDim Preserve aParam(i)
   aParam(i) = vParam
   i = i + 1
  Next
 ElseIf TypeName(adParam) = "Double" Or TypeName(adParam) = "String" Then  'we have a single value, either a double or a string
  ReDim aParam(0)
  aParam(0) = adParam
 End If
 'now we have an array (one dimensional) in any case

 For i = LBound(aParam) To UBound(aParam)
  ReDim Preserve aResult(i)
  aResult(i) = Val(Replace(aParam(i), "½", ".5")) 'this is the function's main operation.
 Next

 If UBound(aResult) = 0 Then
  'if only one result
  arrayFriendlyUDF = aResult(0)
 Else
  'return the array of results
  arrayFriendlyUDF = aResult
 End If

End Function
```

Sheet:

[image]

My locale is German. So decimal delimiter is comma.

Formulas:

in `B1:B9`: `=arrayFriendlyUDF(A1)`

in `D2:L2`: `=arrayFriendlyUDF(D2)`

in `A11`: `=SUM(arrayFriendlyUDF(A1:A9))`

in `N1`: `=SUM(arrayFriendlyUDF(D1:L1))`

In this case array context is not necessary. But the formula can be used in array context too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following User Defined Function =UDFSumstring(A1:B10)
No need for array formula just <kbd>Enter</kbd>
This UDF

- substitute all "½" to ".5"
- Convert the string to its value
- Sum the result
- For a Range (A1:B10) not just (A1:A2)

> 

```
Function UDFSumstring(ByVal cell_range As Range) As Double    
>         Dim i As Long, j As Long, total As Double
>         Dim varray As Variant, sv As Double
>         varray = cell_range.Value>       
>         For i = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)
>             For j = 1 To UBound(varray, 2)
>                 If InStr(1, varray(i, j), "½") > 0 Then
>                 sv = Val(WorksheetFunction.Substitute(varray(i, j), "½", ".5"))
>                 Else
>                 sv = Val(varray(i, j))
>                 End If
>             total = total + sv
>             Next
>         Next
>         
>         UDFSumstring = total
>         
>         End Function
```

Comment: The outcome is more complex than that in fact. It isn't not just the double as the exemple, but it has to go into every cell to get another value out (f.ex: 2½ in a cell will get the value of 2.5 etc.), so I can't use your suggestion because 2½ + 2½ will get an error

Comment: You mean UDF is converting the Fraction and Sum will add the result?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I would like.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. The idea is usable for my question. You're very close to get the accepted answer, but I give it to @Axel Richter because of his greater usablity towards an array function.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it so the function is called twice (or how every many times required) in your formula.

Make your function return a value as such:

```
 Public Function myUserDefinedFkt(value) As Double
     If InStr(1, value, "1/2") > 0 Then
        myUserDefinedFkt = CDbl(Left(value, Len(value) - 4) & ".5")
     Else
        myUserDefinedFkt = CDbl(value)
     End If
 End Function
```

Then write your formula like this in your worksheet:

```
=myuserdefinedfkt(A1)+myuserdefinedfkt(B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What, I want is the most elegant solution. Imagine I have a row/column of 1234 entries, the formula will be very long! Best solution here is the looping over the entire range of cells in the myUserDefinedFkt suggested by @YowE3K.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but there are ways to return array without loop:

```
Public Function f(v)
    v = Application.Transpose(v)    ' 2D to 1D because Join needs 1D array
    v = Join(v, ";")                ' "1½;2½"
    v = Replace(v, "½", ".5")       ' "1.5;2.5"
    f = Evaluate("{" & v & "}")     ' {1.5;2.5}
End Function
```

A bit more complicated if it needs to work for row or single cell too:

```
Public Function f(v)
    Let v = v               ' Range to 2D Array or value
    If IsArray(v) Then
        If UBound(v, 1) = 1 Then
            v = Application.Index(v, 1, 0)  ' 2D row array to 1D
            v = "{" & Join(v, ",") & "}"    ' Join needs 1D array
        Else
            v = Application.Transpose(v)    ' 2D column array to 1D
            v = "{" & Join(v, ";") & "}"    ' ; is row separator
        End If
    End If
    v = Replace(v, "½", ".5")   ' "{1.5;2.5}"
    f = Evaluate(v)             '  {1.5;2.5}
End Function
```

But the best and fastest option is most likely with For loops:

```
Public Function f(v)
    Let v = v               ' Range to 2D Array or value
    If Not IsArray(v) Then f = Val(Replace(v, "½", ".5")): Exit Function

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
            v(r, c) = Val(Replace(v(r, c), "½", ".5"))
        Next c
    Next r
    f = v
End Function
```

---

In Excel 2016, the [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function can be used to flatten any range to array (not tested):

```
Public Function f(r As Range)
    f = r.Worksheet.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN(("","",1," & r.Address & ")")    ' "1½,2½"
    f = Replace(f, "½", ".5")                                           ' "1.5,2.5"
    f = Evaluate("{" & f & "}")                                         ' {1.5,2.5}
End Function
```